# SQL Agent Job executes delete statement instead of Delete-Insert

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-job

I have written a stored procedure, code shown below. I have scheduled a job to execute this stored procedure. The job executes the procedure in 10 seconds and deletes the table but **DOESN'T** insert any rows. The stored procedure, when executed manually, deletes and inserts 2800 rows. The stored procedure syntax is correct. It looks like the job only deletes the table and stops executing thereafter. The job doesn't reports any errors.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Dim.Test
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION Trans1

    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE FROM [Fact].[CommissionLiveData];
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [Fact].[CommissionLiveData] (ProjectSID,
Project,
ProjectID_Char,
ProjectHyperlink,
OpportunityHyperlink,
OpportunitySID,
Opportunity,
MasterCustomerSID,
MasterCustomer,
OwnerSID,
Owner,
ProjectStartdateSID,
ProjectStartDate,
TeamSID,
Team,
CommercialTeam,
PortfolioSID,
Portfolio,
OpportunityTypeSID,
OpportunityType,
ActualCloseDateSID,
ActualCloseDate,
RevenueSplit,
durationmonths,
RevenueDateSID,
RevenueDate,
RevenueQuarter,
RevenueYear,
MonthTCV,
OpportunityTCV,
OpportunityACV,
NewCustomerFlag,
ClosedIn2023Flag,
ManagedServicesFlag,
RevenueRecognitionFlag,
TCVTargetFlag,
RevenueTargetFlag,
NNPTargetFlag,
ACVTargetFlag,
Level5Flag,
ActiveEmployeeFlag,
Currency,
RevAdj,
GP,
GPPct,
BaseRate,
GPBooster,
BaseCommissionRate,
DealSizeBooster,
DealTypeBooster,
DealDurationBooster,
TA_ACVBooster,
TA_TCVBooster,
TA_NNPBooster,
TA_RevenueBooster,
TABooster,
MSBooster,
NewCustomerBooster,
PublicCloudBooster,
Commission2023,
Commission2022,
Level5Deductions
)
SELECT  
c.[ProjectSID]  as  ProjectSID,
c.[Project] as  Project,
c.[ProjectID_Char]  as  ProjectID_Char,
c.[ProjectHyperlink]    as  ProjectHyperlink,
c.[OpportunityHyperlink]    as  OpportunityHyperlink,
c.[OpportunitySID]  as  OpportunitySID,
c.[Opportunity] as  Opportunity,
c.[MasterCustomerSID]   as  MasterCustomerSID,
c.[MasterCustomer]  as  MasterCustomer,
c.[OwnerSID]    as  OwnerSID,
c.[Owner]   as  Owner,
c.[ProjectStartdateSID] as  ProjectStartdateSID,
c.[ProjectStartDate]    as  ProjectStartDate,
c.[TeamSID] as  TeamSID,
c.[Team]    as  Team,
c.[CommercialTeam]  as  CommercialTeam,
c.[PortfolioSID]    as  PortfolioSID,
c.[Portfolio]   as  Portfolio,
c.[OpportunityTypeSID]  as  OpportunityTypeSID,
c.[OpportunityType] as  OpportunityType,
c.[ActualCloseDateSID]  as  ActualCloseDateSID,
c.[ActualCloseDate] as  ActualCloseDate,
c.[RevenueSplit]    as  RevenueSplit,
c.[durationmonths]  as  durationmonths,
c.[RevenueDateSID]  as  RevenueDateSID,
c.[RevenueDate] as  RevenueDate,
c.[RevenueQuarter]  as  RevenueQuarter,
c.[RevenueYear] as  RevenueYear,
c.[MonthTCV]    as  MonthTCV,
c.[OpportunityTCV]  as  OpportunityTCV,
c.[OpportunityACV]  as  OpportunityACV,
c.[NewCustomerFlag] as  NewCustomerFlag,
c.[ClosedIn2023Flag]    as  ClosedIn2023Flag,
c.[ManagedServicesFlag] as  ManagedServicesFlag,
c.[RevenueRecognitionFlag]  as  RevenueRecognitionFlag,
c.[TCVTargetFlag]   as  TCVTargetFlag,
c.[RevenueTargetFlag]   as  RevenueTargetFlag,
c.[NNPTargetFlag]   as  NNPTargetFlag,
c.[ACVTargetFlag]   as  ACVTargetFlag,
c.[Level5Flag]  as  Level5Flag,
c.[ActiveEmployeeFlag]  as  ActiveEmployeeFlag,
c.[Currency]    as  Currency,
c.[RevAdj]  as  RevAdj,
c.[GP]  as  GP,
c.[GPPct]   as  GPPct,
c.[BaseRate]    as  BaseRate,
c.[GPBooster]   as  GPBooster,
c.[BaseCommissionRate]  as  BaseCommissionRate,
c.[DealSizeBooster] as  DealSizeBooster,
c.[DealTypeBooster] as  DealTypeBooster,
c.[DealDurationBooster] as  DealDurationBooster,
c.[TA_ACVBooster]   as  TA_ACVBooster,
c.[TA_TCVBooster]   as  TA_TCVBooster,
c.[TA_NNPBooster]   as  TA_NNPBooster,                    
c.[TA_RevenueBooster]   as  TA_RevenueBooster,
c.[TABooster]   as  TABooster,
c.[MSBooster]   as  MSBooster,
c.[NewCustomerBooster]  as  NewCustomerBooster,
c.[PublicCloudBooster]  as  PublicCloudBooster,
c.[Commission2023]  as  Commission2023,
c.[Commission2022]  as  Commission2022,
c.[Level5Deductions]    as  Level5Deductions
FROM 
(SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) IN (2,5,8,11) AND (DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())) > 8 THEN 1 
                                           WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) IN (3,6,9,12) THEN 1
                                           ELSE 0 END CRF,* FROM [Presentation].[vDimCommissionData]) c
WHERE ( c.RevenueDate >= DATEADD( QUARTER, DATEDIFF( QUARTER, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND CRF = 1)  
OR (c.RevenueDate >= DATEADD( QUARTER, DATEDIFF( QUARTER, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND CRF = 0);
 --If revenue date is greater than or equal to the 9th day in the second month of the quarter,   We will display current quarters information and onwards else Previous quarter information and onwards 
END TRY


BEGIN CATCH
      SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;
```

Updated code:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Dim.Test
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION Trans1
        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE FROM [Fact].[CommissionLiveData];

            INSERT INTO [Fact].[CommissionLiveData] (ProjectSID,
Project,
ProjectID_Char,
ProjectHyperlink,
OpportunityHyperlink,
OpportunitySID,
Opportunity,
MasterCustomerSID,
MasterCustomer,
OwnerSID,
Owner,
ProjectStartdateSID,
ProjectStartDate,
TeamSID,
Team,
CommercialTeam,
PortfolioSID,
Portfolio,
OpportunityTypeSID,
OpportunityType,
ActualCloseDateSID,
ActualCloseDate,
RevenueSplit,
durationmonths,
RevenueDateSID,
RevenueDate,
RevenueQuarter,
RevenueYear,
MonthTCV,
OpportunityTCV,
OpportunityACV,
NewCustomerFlag,
ClosedIn2023Flag,
ManagedServicesFlag,
RevenueRecognitionFlag,
TCVTargetFlag,
RevenueTargetFlag,
NNPTargetFlag,
ACVTargetFlag,
Level5Flag,
ActiveEmployeeFlag,
Currency,
RevAdj,
GP,
GPPct,
BaseRate,
GPBooster,
BaseCommissionRate,
DealSizeBooster,
DealTypeBooster,
DealDurationBooster,
TA_ACVBooster,
TA_TCVBooster,
TA_NNPBooster,
TA_RevenueBooster,
TABooster,
MSBooster,
NewCustomerBooster,
PublicCloudBooster,
Commission2023,
Commission2022,
Level5Deductions
)
SELECT  
c.[ProjectSID]  as  ProjectSID,
c.[Project] as  Project,
c.[ProjectID_Char]  as  ProjectID_Char,
c.[ProjectHyperlink]    as  ProjectHyperlink,
c.[OpportunityHyperlink]    as  OpportunityHyperlink,
c.[OpportunitySID]  as  OpportunitySID,
c.[Opportunity] as  Opportunity,
c.[MasterCustomerSID]   as  MasterCustomerSID,
c.[MasterCustomer]  as  MasterCustomer,
c.[OwnerSID]    as  OwnerSID,
c.[Owner]   as  Owner,
c.[ProjectStartdateSID] as  ProjectStartdateSID,
c.[ProjectStartDate]    as  ProjectStartDate,
c.[TeamSID] as  TeamSID,
c.[Team]    as  Team,
c.[CommercialTeam]  as  CommercialTeam,
c.[PortfolioSID]    as  PortfolioSID,
c.[Portfolio]   as  Portfolio,
c.[OpportunityTypeSID]  as  OpportunityTypeSID,
c.[OpportunityType] as  OpportunityType,
c.[ActualCloseDateSID]  as  ActualCloseDateSID,
c.[ActualCloseDate] as  ActualCloseDate,
c.[RevenueSplit]    as  RevenueSplit,
c.[durationmonths]  as  durationmonths,
c.[RevenueDateSID]  as  RevenueDateSID,
c.[RevenueDate] as  RevenueDate,
c.[RevenueQuarter]  as  RevenueQuarter,
c.[RevenueYear] as  RevenueYear,
c.[MonthTCV]    as  MonthTCV,
c.[OpportunityTCV]  as  OpportunityTCV,
c.[OpportunityACV]  as  OpportunityACV,
c.[NewCustomerFlag] as  NewCustomerFlag,
c.[ClosedIn2023Flag]    as  ClosedIn2023Flag,
c.[ManagedServicesFlag] as  ManagedServicesFlag,
c.[RevenueRecognitionFlag]  as  RevenueRecognitionFlag,
c.[TCVTargetFlag]   as  TCVTargetFlag,
c.[RevenueTargetFlag]   as  RevenueTargetFlag,
c.[NNPTargetFlag]   as  NNPTargetFlag,
c.[ACVTargetFlag]   as  ACVTargetFlag,
c.[Level5Flag]  as  Level5Flag,
c.[ActiveEmployeeFlag]  as  ActiveEmployeeFlag,
c.[Currency]    as  Currency,
c.[RevAdj]  as  RevAdj,
c.[GP]  as  GP,
c.[GPPct]   as  GPPct,
c.[BaseRate]    as  BaseRate,
c.[GPBooster]   as  GPBooster,
c.[BaseCommissionRate]  as  BaseCommissionRate,
c.[DealSizeBooster] as  DealSizeBooster,
c.[DealTypeBooster] as  DealTypeBooster,
c.[DealDurationBooster] as  DealDurationBooster,
c.[TA_ACVBooster]   as  TA_ACVBooster,
c.[TA_TCVBooster]   as  TA_TCVBooster,
c.[TA_NNPBooster]   as  TA_NNPBooster,                    
c.[TA_RevenueBooster]   as  TA_RevenueBooster,
c.[TABooster]   as  TABooster,
c.[MSBooster]   as  MSBooster,
c.[NewCustomerBooster]  as  NewCustomerBooster,
c.[PublicCloudBooster]  as  PublicCloudBooster,
c.[Commission2023]  as  Commission2023,
c.[Commission2022]  as  Commission2022,
c.[Level5Deductions]    as  Level5Deductions
FROM 
(SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) IN (2,5,8,11) AND (DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())) > 8 THEN 1 
                                           WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) IN (3,6,9,12) THEN 1
                                           ELSE 0 END CRF,* FROM [Presentation].[vDimCommissionData]) c
WHERE ( c.RevenueDate >= DATEADD( QUARTER, DATEDIFF( QUARTER, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND CRF = 1)  
OR (c.RevenueDate >= DATEADD( QUARTER, DATEDIFF( QUARTER, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND CRF = 0);
 --If revenue date is greater than or equal to the 9th day in the second month of the quarter,   We will display current quarters information and onwards else Previous quarter information and onwards 

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
          SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Can you please help me with what exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the user with whom you are launching the job have the correct permissions on the table?

Comment: Your transaction handling is a bit suspect. surely you want to keep delete + insert together. Right now, you delete separately so if insert fails you'll get no data at all. I'd probably change it to: `begin tran delete... insert ... commit tran`

Comment: @raBinn What kind of permissions?

Comment: @siggemannen the transactions was added later. Initially the SP had simple delete and insert commands without any transaction/try-catch. I added to test if it works with trans/try-catch code block.

Comment: Well, the handling is still suspect, regardless of when you added it :)

Comment: @siggemannen do you want me to merge delete select insert in single transcation

Comment: There's little point of transacting a single statement, since SQL Server wraps single statement in implicit transaction anyway, and if error occurs, it is rollbacked. So yeah, i think it will work better with both statement under same transaction

Comment: @siggemannen See updated code. This still deletes the table doesn't insert records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256025/discussion-between-xorpower-and-siggemannen).

Answer (score 1):

You missed committing the transaction if the insert-select is successful.

Also, you will need to test doing it step-by-step and see whether the select used in the insert-select is not empty.

But the solution seems to be to just commit the transaction if there was no error.

Comment: What did I miss? The select used in insert-select is not empty. This was tested. It has 2800 records which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @xorpower after your insert-select I do not see a `COMMIT TRANSACTION;` after success.

Comment: Check now in the updated code  section. The Job still inserts 0 records @Lajos

Comment: What does the select return at that point?